# PhpStorm Is there a way to turn "differences only" on on Difference viewer

Tags: phpstorm

PhpStorm Is there a way  to turn "differences only" on on Difference viewer

This view will show a concise view of only the differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like Beyond Compare has (for example) where only lines with differences are shown?

AFAIK -- no.

But you may use `"Collapse unchanged fragments"` button on diff viewer toolbar and it will leave 3-4 lines of context around modified lines hiding the rest of the unmodified code. This can be used in both "Side-by-side viewer" mode (2 panels -- right and left) and "Unified viewer" mode (all merged into one view).

For example (PhpStorm 2016.3.2 using "unified viewer" mode):

[image]

*(the only difference between these 2 files are those few added lines with green background)*